# JSON.parse(message) fails but "https://jsonlint.com/" shows that the message is valid. Why does this happen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

It fails here,

```
message = "{\"response\":{\"billDetails\":\"[{\"name\":\"Account ID\"}]\"}}"
JSON.parse(message)
JSON::ParserError (809: unexpected token at '{"response":{"billDetails":"[{"name":"Account ID"}]"}}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this will be helpful. But your json string should be written from

```
"{
  "response":{
    "billDetails": "[{"name":"Account ID"}]"}
}"
```

To:

```
'{
  "response":{
    "billDetails": [{"name":"Account ID"}]
    }
}'
```

In the array from billDetails, you have two aditional ", that provokes an error when parsing that string.

Comment: Thank you sir. I used gsub to replace the additional quotes and it works. :) This issue exists with all types of paranthesis. json lint validator is wrong i guess.